# What's the difference between metric tensor and inner product?

Tags: differential-geometry

I understand that inner product requires positive-definiteness while metric tensor only requires non-degeneracy.  But what intuition does the metric tensor definition serve?

Comment: Indeed a metric tensor can be degenerate (see http://www.springer.com/in/book/9780792339960).

Answer (score 1):

The standard example of a metric tensor that is not positive definite is the Lorentz metric of space-time.